# Binomial Distribution Problem (usb sticks)

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Each USB stick produced by certain factory has 0.065 probability of being defective, regardless of other USB sticks produced. The factory sells them in packages containing 30 and guarantees a refund if a costumer buys a package and at least one pendrive is defective.

**a)** What is the probability of the factory having to refund a client?

**b)** If a customer buys 9 packages, what is the probability that he/she receives his/her money back for just one of them?

*I have the answers here, I just can't figure out how to achive them*

a)0.867

b)0 (zero)

Comment: The probability in the case b) is certainly strictly greater than zero.

Comment: I thought that was strange too. But anyway, still can't reach any value similar to those from a).

Comment: The factory will not have to refund the client if and only if all 30 USB sticks in the package are not defective. What do you think is the probability of this event?

Comment: Wow, thank you very much sir. It would be a binomial distribution with 30 success in 30 trials. 1 - P(X=30) equals 0.867. It was hard for me to see that, but now I think I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give the answers:

- the probability a single pendrive is defective is $0.065$ and that it is not defective is $1-0.065=0.935$
- the probability none of a package of thirty pendrives is defective is $0.935^{30} \approx   0.1331522$ so the probability at least one in a package of thirty is defective is about $1- 0.1331522 = 0.8668478$
- The probability exactly one package out of nine contains at least one faulty pendrive is about $9 \times 0.8668478 \times 0.1331522^{8} \approx 0.00000077$, which is not far from zero